# for loop range values

Tags: python, loops

Please see my code below

```
for i in range (0,3):
    url = "number/i"
    print url
```

My expectation is

```
number/1
number/2
number/3
```

Can I also change URL to URL1= number/1 URL2=number/2 as well?

Comment: Why would `i` in a string literal be changed to the value of a variable `i`? Why don't you expect any of the other letters to change? What if you wrote `interesting/i`, how many of the `i`s should be changed to a number, and how does Python know? ... It's because characters in strings are not variables.

Answer (score 2):

Pythons [range](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) defaults to starting at 0, and runs to **one less that the stop value**, in your case it will give `0, 1, 2`. You can either add one to get the values you want, or adjust your range to `range(1, 4)`

Then, to get the printed output you want, you'll need to convert the number to a string, like so

```
url = "number/" + str(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
url = "number/i"
```

To:

```
url = "number/"+str(i+1)
```